# Как выровнять заголовки относительно друг друга с помощью CSS

Tags: html, css, css3

Последний заголовок почему-то находится ниже других и второй не совсем ровно размешен. Помогите, пожалуйста. Как выровнять заголовки относительно друг друга?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вот код: https://codepen.io/Maref/pen/GRgKOLJ

Comment: задай одинаковую высоту картинкам

Answer (score 1, accepted):

просто для картинок задай высоту одинаковую

```
    .s2img
    {
      height:120px;
        margin-bottom: 40px;
        text-align: center;
    }
```

https://codepen.io/saneQ1/pen/QWwLaQm

Comment: Спасибо, помог.